# Error in XInternAtom as ' X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'

Tags: x11, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run our game application on ubuntu 16.0.4 and it throws the following error:

```
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
   Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
   Value in failed request:  0x0
   Serial number of failed request:  42
   Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

I ran the backtrace on my application and got the following:

```
Thread 34 (Thread 0xa11f9b40 (LWP 20075)):
#0  0x010d2e74 in g2s::engine::G2SMtp::~G2SMtp (this=0x2383c94 <g2sEngine+4660>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
at g2sengine/g2smtp.cpp:42
#1  0x00f997b8 in g2s::engine::G2SEngine::~G2SEngine (this=0x2382a60 <g2sEngine>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
at ../../include/../src/g2senginelib/g2sengine/g2sengine.h:75
#2  0xb64e0973 in __run_exit_handlers (status=1, listp=0xb66643dc <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=true) at exit.c:82
#3  0xb64e09cf in __GI_exit (status=1) at exit.c:104
#4  0xb6b72109 in _XDefaultError () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#5  0xb6b7223a in _XError () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#6  0xb6b6f1db in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#7  0xb6b6f29f in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#8  0xb6b7017e in _XReply () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#9  0xb6b5a755 in XInternAtom () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#10 0x005f310d in start_x11_screen (nscreen=0, Xres=1280, Yres=1024, client_visual_attributes=0x0) at glxctx.c:4596
```

I would like to know how to read the X11 errors, is there a reference manual which can give me details corresponding to numbers **155 (GLX)** , **3 (X_GLXCreateContext)** and **42** , **44**. How to read these errors ?

Also,any idea what could be wrong here ?